# What is the difference between path() and re_path()?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

In Django2.0 were introduced [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/urls/#path) and [`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path).

But the difference between boths is unclear to me : is it about the ability to use or not regexps with it?

Would that mean that I couldn't use both `<type:name>` and `(?P<name>\d+)` syntaxes in the same pattern?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For my understanding is that the `path` function does not accept regex urls anymore, you need to use the new urls syntax `<slug:title>` instead of passing a regex to match parameters. The `re_path` only work with regex formatted urls (The old way we make urls).